# Magento 2 how to add all Indian cities as drop down

Tags: magento2, ui-form

I am trying to add All Indian cities come as drop with respect to their state,i got country and state dropdown but unable to add city. can i get help? thank you in advance.
here is my `form.xml` file

```
<field name="country_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Vendor\My_Module\Model\Store\Source\Country</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Country</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">country</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">80</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/country</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="region">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">State/Region</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Timeslot</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">65</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="state_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">State/Region</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Timeslot</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
                    <item name="customEntry" xsi:type="string">region</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id</item>
                        <item name="field" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field formElement="input" name="city_id" sortOrder="70">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Timeslot</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">City</label>
                <dataScope>city_id</dataScope>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
            </settings>
        </field>
```

Comment: use this extension https://github.com/EaDesgin/Magento2-City-Dropdown

Comment: Thank You amit Bera